# Security firewall logout path redirects to http instead of https protocol

Tags: symfony, security, https, logout, symfony-security

Security firewall logout path redirects to http instead of https protocol.

I've tried adding annotation parameters, like: `schemes={"https"}`

Also I added in security.yaml, the path to the logout route.

```
- { path: /api/v1/user/logout-result, requires_channel: https }
```

Still to no luck. Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: Please show the configuration of your firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my issue.

I removed the target property from logout and added success_handler, which points to my custom service class.

The custom service class auto-injects the RouterInterface and its function

`public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)`

returns new RedirectResponse object which points to the `/api/v1/user/logout-result` route.